# form:checkbox/form:<anything> not rendering/displaying in Spring 4, input type="radio”/input type="checkbox" does

Tags: spring, jsp, checkbox

I have been asked to upgrade an application that was using Spring 3 (3.1.4.RELEASE  and 3.2.5.RELEASE in POM) and have gone to (4.2.2.RELEASE and 4.3.8.RELEASE) respectively (for numerous dependencies. The application used to render correctly, show the JSP but now using any of the existing `form:checkbox`/`form:radiobutton`/`form:input/form:errors` work as the page is just blank, no errors. When I re-write the code and use `input type="checkbox”`/`input type="radio"` etc the page now shows ok.

I have looked around loads of examples/forums but nothing I have tried has helped. Am I missing some configuration change elsewhere that is needed? The server is WildFly too, but the application worked fine on this using Spring 3 dependencies.

Example of the JSP (with `form:radiobutton`/`form:checkbox` commented out and the other code below it that displays ok), called manageUser.jsp :-

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<%@ taglib uri = "http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix = "form"%>       

<div class="contentWrapper">
    <fieldset>
        <c:if test="${infoFlag}">
            <div id="pageMessage">
                <p><spring:message code="${infoMessage}"/></p>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${successFlag !=null && successFlag}">
            <div class='message glbMsg success ajaxMsg'>
                <span class="infoicon">&nbsp;</span><p><spring:message code="${successMessage}"/></p>
            </div>
        </c:if>
    <div>
        <h3>Manage Users</h3>
        <p id="pageIntro">
            This section allows you to manage or create users and assign users to roles.
        </p>
    <div class="col">           
        <div id="user-tab-container" class="user-tab-container manage-user-page">
            <ul class='etabs'>
                <li class='usertab'><a href="#manage-user" id="click-manage-user">Manage User</a></li>
                <li class='usertab'><a href="#create-user" id="click-create-user" data-href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/createUser.do">Create User</a></li>
                <li class='usertab' style="display:none;"><a href="#search-user" id="click-search-user" data-href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/searchUserResult.jsp">User Search</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class='panel-container'>
                <div id="manage-user">
                    <form:form id="searchUser" class="singleColForm" method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/searchUser.do" modelAttribute="user">   
                        <div class="col mrgTop10">
                            <div class="col w2">                    
                                <div class="frmFld">
                                    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
                                    <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" class="alphanumeric" maxlength="45" value="${user.lastName}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="frmFld">
                                    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                                    <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" class="alphanumeric" maxlength="45" value="${user.firstName}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="frmFld">
                                    <label for="eMail">E-mail</label>
                                    <input id="eMail" name="eMail" type="text" class="email" maxlength="100" value="${user.eMail}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="frmFld multiRadio">
                                    <label>Status</label>
                                    <div class="scrollableUserGroup">   

                                        <span class="radio"> 
                                            <input id="userStatus[All]" name="userStatus" type="radio" value="-1" checked/>
                                            <label for="userStatus[All]">All</label>
                                        </span>
                                        <!-- Original that doesn't work now -->
<%--                                        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${userStatusList}"> --%>
<%--                                            <span class="radio"> <form:radiobutton --%>
<%--                                                    id="userStatus[${entry.name}]" name="userStatus" --%>
<%--                                                    path="userStatus" value="${entry.id}" /> <label --%>
<%--                                                for="userStatus[${entry.name}]"><c:out value="${entry.name}"/></label> --%>
<!--                                            </span> -->
<%--                                        </c:forEach> --%>

                                        <c:forEach var="entry" items="${userStatusList}">
                                            <span class="radio">
                                                <input type="radio" id="userStatus[${entry.name}]" name="userStatus" value="${entry.id}">
                                                <label for="userStatus[${entry.name}]"><c:out value="${entry.name}"/></label>
                                            </span>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col w2">
                                <label>User Groups</label>
                                <div class="frmFld">
                                    <div class="scrollableUserGroup scrollableUserGroups">

                                    <!-- Original that doesn't work now --> 
<%--                                    <c:forEach items="${userGroup}" var="group"> --%>
<!--                                        <div class="userCB"> -->
<!--                                            <span class="customCB checkbox">  -->
<%--                                            <form:checkbox  path="userGroups" value="${group.id}" />  --%>
<!--                                                <span class="box"> -->
<!--                                                    <span class="tick">&nbsp;</span> -->
<!--                                                </span> -->
<!--                                            </span> -->
<%--                                            <label class="breakword" style="margin-left: 20px;"><c:out value="${group.name}"/></label> --%>

<!--                                        </div> -->
<%--                                    </c:forEach>     --%>

                                        <c:forEach items="${userGroup}" var="group">
                                            <div class="userCB">
                                                <span class="customCB checkbox"> 
                                                    <input type="checkbox" value="${group.id}" name="userGroups" id="${lstPermission.id}">
                                                    <span class="box">
                                                        <span class="tick">&nbsp;</span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                                <label class="breakword" style="margin-left: 20px;"><c:out value="${group.name}"/></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </c:forEach>    
                                    </div>                                          
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <a class="btn Big searchUser" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/admin/searchUser.do">Search user <span>&nbsp;</span></a> 
                            <span class="hidden">&nbsp;</span>
                        </div>
                    </form:form>    
                </div>

                <div id="create-user">
                    <!-- Create user -->
                </div>
                <div id="search-user">
                    <!-- search user -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

In another file called tiles-definition.xml it has the JSP filename:-

```
<definition name="manageUser"  template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/user/manageUser.jsp" />
```

In the Controller, it has (with irrelevant other parts removed):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class UserControllerImpl extends AbstractCommonController implements UserController {
```

Below is used in JSP

```
    @ModelAttribute("userStatusList")
    public Set<UserStatus> populateUserStatus(){
        return userHelper.getUserStatusCollection();
    }

    @ModelAttribute("userGroup")
    public Set<UserGroup> populateUserGroup(){
        return userHelper.getUserGroupCollection();
    }
…


    @RequestMapping("/manageUser.do")
    public String manageUser(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request){
        model.put("user", new UserTo());
        return "manageUser";
    }
…
}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml (has the below in it along with some other parts that are needed):-

```
…
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
    </bean>
```

POM.xml has (old version commented out, new added in) :-

```
…
        <!-- Spring web dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>  -->
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>  -->
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>  -->
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>  -->
            <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>  -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
<!--             <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version> -->
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help is much appreciated as I have been thrown in the deep end not knowing too much about Spring and would like to understand and get the original `form:radiobutton`/`form:checkbox`/etc working (displaying) and not use the re-written style. Is anything else required for suggestions?